# Сравнение вложенных списков

Tags: python, list

У меня есть два вложенных списка длинной 45, к примеру вот таких:

```
a = [['a','d','c','f'], ['w','r','t','c'], ['w','r','t','y'], ['r','t','t']]
b = [['q','w','e'], ['r','t','z'], ['t','y','t'], ['t','t','y']]
```

Но только вложены не по 4 элемента, а 45. Нужно создать список `c`, в котором будут посчитаны количество совпадение элементов в списке `а` с элементами в списке `b`.

В итоге хочу получить вот такой список:

```
с = [[0], [2], [2], [2]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно прикрутить [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter
a = [['a','d','c','f'], ['w','r','t','c'], ['w','r','t','y'], ['r','t','t']]
b = [['q','w','e'], ['r','t','z'], ['t','y','t'], ['t', 't','y']]
r = ([sum((Counter(a) & Counter(b)).values())] for a, b in zip(a, b))
print(list(r))
```

**Вывод:**

`[[0], [2], [2], [2]]`

[Демо](https://rextester.com/FTEQYC13942).

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [['a','d','c','f'], ['w','r','t','c'], ['w','r','t','y'    ], ['r','t','t']]
b = [['q','w','e'    ], [    'r','t','z'], [        't','y','t'], [    't','t','y']]
#                             +   +                  +   +              +   +

c = []

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    n = 0
    for j in v:
        if j in b[i]:
            n += 1
            ind = b[i].index(j)
            b[i].pop(ind)
    c.append([n])

print(c)
```

---

```
[[0], [2], [2], [2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ответам, результат, всё-таки, должен быть `[[0], [2], [2], [2]]`, а не `[[0], [1], [1], [2]]`, что сбивает с толку. Если ответ для данных `a` и `b` действительно должен быть `[[0], [2], [2], [2]]`, то решение в одну строку без использования каких-либо модулей будет выглядеть так:

```py
c = [[sum(e in y for e in x)] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: Да, вы правы. Отредактировала вопрос.